# Error While trying to setup mod wsgi in windows apache

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I installed `mod_wsgi` module in `apache` by copying it into the modules directory and then changing the `httpd.conf` file accordingly by adding `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so`.

The directory block that I included is as follows:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi “C:/Django-1.5.1/wsgi/wsgi_handler.py”

<Directory “C:/Django-1.5.1/wsgi”>
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

However on starting apache I get the following error:

```
Syntax error on line 243 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
<Directory "\xe2\x80\x9cC:/Django-1.5.1/wsgi\xe2\x80\x9d"> path is invalid.
```

I do not understand why that garbage is being appended to the path.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You likely are mixing 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Apache. Python and mod_wsgi. You must use all 32 bit or all 64 bit. Use binaries from:

- http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

Using the distribution of Apache they used to build mod_wsgi.

Comment: Python is 32 bit how do I check the others?

Comment: Don't know about Apache. Just try reinstalling and make sure you download the same for all. Also make sure you are installing the correct version of Python for the mod_wsgi binary you are using.

Comment: Well I did that it does not work for me. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Hmm, should have read your message properly. You have wrong sort of quotes in your file. Get rid of those fancy non standard quotes.